# Convert a string of numbers to a list of integers. Python

Tags: string, list, python-2.7

I am trying to convert the string str1 to a list of numbers so that I could sum them up. First I use the split() function to make sense of the numbers in str1, I cast the string into a list (lista) and after that I use the map() function in order to convert the strings in the new list to integers:

```
   str1="13,22,32,4,5"

   str2=str1.split()
   lista=list(str2)

   lista=map(int,lista)

   print sum(lista)
```

For some reason I get the following error message: "ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '13,22,32,4,5'"

Answer (score 2):

Using `split()` will not split up `str1`, as without the `sep` argument the default separator is a space `' '`. Hence:

```
str2 == ["13,22,32,4,5"]
```

you need to specify that `split` should use a comma `','`. In fact, you can combine your operations into one:

```
sum(map(int, str1.split(',')))
```

Comment: I see what you did there. I managed to make mine work only by adding (",") to the split function parentheses. Thank you!

Comment: You don't need to call `lista = list(str2)`; `split` returns a list, so you can use `lista = str1.split(',')`