# Converting a string entry of list to integer in python

Tags: python, list, python-3.x

I have a list like this:

```
['1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8']
```

which is a list of length 1 containing a string.

I would like to convert this list to

```
[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]
```

i.e. a list of 8 integers.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convert a string of numbers to a list of integers. Python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21026726/convert-a-string-of-numbers-to-a-list-of-integers-python)

Answer (score 3):

```
>>> map(int, ['1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8'][0].split(','))
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]
```

Tested in Python 2.7.3

Comment: it tried it in python 3.5. Shell and doesn't work for me .. am i missing out sth here ?>>> map(int, ['1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8'][0].split(','))
<map object at 0x103f1fdd8>

Comment: @p.ranjan in python3, you must make a list out of the map object explicitly, i.e. `list(map(int, ['1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8'][0].split(',')))`.

Comment: @p.ranjan:  Wrap the whole thing in `list()`.  In Python 3, `map` returns a `map` object.

Comment: >> list(map(int, ['1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8'][0].split(',')))
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#30>", line 1, in <module>
    list(map(int, ['1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8'][0].split(',')))
TypeError: 'list' object is not callable

Comment: @p.ranjan:  Restart your interpreter.  You have assigned to `list` thus hiding the builtin.  Don't do that.

Comment: @StevenRumbalski: Thanks. that worked for me ! i've one more question next .. now that i got the list , say, lst = [1,2,3,4,5,6]. i am trying to assign this list to a key in dictionary using my_dict.setdefault(m_qid.group(1),list()).append(lst) -- when i do that, the dctionary key gets a list of list ([[1,2,3,4,5,6]]) , but i wanted was the key to be assigned just this list ! any tips ?? thanks.

Comment: Then simply do `my_dict[m_qid.group(1)] = lst`.

Comment: Or `my_dict.setdefault(m_qid.group(1),list()).extend(lst)`.

Answer (score 3):

list comprehension with the `split` command works well for this.

```
>>> lst = ['1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8'][0]
>>> [int(i) for i in lst.split(',')]
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]
```

Answer (score 1):

With `ast.literal_eval`:

```
>>> from ast import literal_eval
>>> list(literal_eval(['1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8'][0]))
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]
```

Comment: This works because `ast.literal_eval('1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8')` interprets that string as a tuple.

Answer (score 1):

I would do it like this:

```
textList = ['1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8']
intList = map(int, textList[0].split(','))
```

There are actually two parts to it - the first step is to split the (only) member of your initial list into a new text list, which has one entry per element:

```
textSplitList = textList[0].split(',')
```

this produces the result ['1', '2', ... etc ]

The second step is to convert the list of strings into a list of integers:

```
intList = map(int, textSplitList)
```

Which gives you the desired result [1, 2, 3, ... etc]

Comment: OP is on Python 3, so `intList = list(map(int, textSplitList))`

Answer (score -1):

Check out the [split](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.split) method for strings. You can say something like `list[0].split(',')` and you can get the values separately.

Comment: That gives a list of strings, not integers.